# only some values are called in the object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a little game to help children with maths as a way to practice my JavaScript as well so I have created this little project.

There is 10 levels to the game, but the problem is that it seems to update only to the levels where the correct answer is always the first in the options section. All others are not loaded. I would appreciate help with this.

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/FrequencyOfLove/pen/NLxQVM

```
let options = [
{"level": [5, 8, 6]},
{"level": [10, 12, 7]},
{"level": [13, 16, 11]},
{"level": [15, 18, 17]},
{"level": [18, 17, 16]},
{"level": [23, 25, 21]},
{"level": [29, 30, 31]},
{"level": [36, 34, 32]},
{"level": [48, 49, 45]},
{"level": [52, 54, 53]}
];

let questions = [
    {"level": [2, 3]},
    {"level": [6, 4]},
    {"level": [9, 4]},
    {"level": [7, 8]},
    {"level": [9, 9]},
    {"level": [11, 12]},
    {"level": [13, 16]},
    {"level": [17, 19]},
    {"level": [23, 25]},
    {"level": [35, 17]}
];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please bear in mind that links to code are not acceptable here.  To improve the quality of your question and avoid it being marked down, please review [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Hi Ian, the problem was solved so this can be closed :)

Comment: In that case, feel free to add your answer, or delete the question :)